# Cloudflare auto minify exluding javascript copyright/license headers

Tags: javascript, licensing, cloudflare

Is it possible to stop Cloudflare auto minify from removing copyright/license headers from specific javascript files? jQuery for example comes with the MIT license that states that all files should have the license statement in them.

Answer (score 0):

Might be something you can do with [PageRule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-)s (exclude URLs from performance features).